# Help me design a Silverlight App (specifically, the Master/Detail Data Entry Form)

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, binding

I am looking for some Design/Architect advice for a Silverlight Application.

This will be a TimeTicket (TimeSheet) application, where employees may go in and enter their daily time.

We have an existing ASP .Net application and database that this new application will "use". The existing application contains Jobs, Quotes, Invoices, Employees, Customers, etc etc etc. It is a full blown Job Cost Financial Application.

We want to start allowing the Employees to enter their own TimeTickets. I have decided to make this a Silverlight application for a few reasons. 1. - To give the Employees a richer interface (most of them don't use the Job Cost application anyway or need access to it) 2. - To separate out the application just to add another layer to help prevent the possibility of Employees accessing sensitive information in the Job Cost application. 3. - I really just want to use Silverlight and improve my WPF/WCF skills (and possibly implement MVVM). And who knows, I might get buy in to rewrite the UI for the main application as a Silverlight app. :)

Ok, more details about this Silverlight application....

There will be some basic "workflow", because the Managers will have to "approve" (and possibly Edit) each Employees TimeSheets. All time is posted to either a Job (which could be an "Overhead" job such as training, meetings, etc) or Attendance (Vacations, Sickness, etc.). Finally,  the TimeTickets will be "posted" to the Job Cost application by someone in Accounting (right now, that person has to enter every ticket from a "paper ticket"!).

The main thing I need help with (although, I will take any advice regarding the application) is the actual TimeTicket Data Entry Form. This will be a Master/Detail (Header/LineItem) type Data Entry Form.

I am strictly looking for guidance for the "Add" form (The "C" of the Crud. lol).... (Although, I am sure I will use the same form for the Edit/Update too.)

The data Entry Form will write to two tables: TimeTicket (Master or Header Table) and TimeTicketDetails (Child or LineItems Table).

If it was an ASP .Net application, I would proably use a FormView for the "Master" and a ListView for the Child. The thing that has me a bit stumped is I would like to have the form begin with about 8 "line items" already in the "list" (or grid). I thought about going ahead and using the MVVM framework (just roll my own, no 3rd party framework or anything like that). That would give me the separation of the Model and ViewModel and when instantiated, I could simply go ahead and add the 8 lines (to the ViewModel) I want to start with. Then, when the user completes the form (and it has been validated of course), I would only add the rows actually used to the database. Thoughts?

I know I may be overcomplicating this! But, for some reason I just can't decide the best way to start. I suppose the biggest reason is just my lack of Silverlight experience.

On a side note, I have been looking at quite a few demos and articles on the WCF RIA services and I am considering using that technology. This is going to start as a pretty small application, but it could grow significantly, so I want to have a good starting point so I can easily expand (and really, I just want to learn some new technologies and frameworks..)

Any advice is much appreciated!

Shayne

Comment: In silverlight you can code the Header view by hands (add labels, textboxes and comboboxes) and use the DataGrid control for the Details view. 8 pre-existing items can be added in the constructor of the related view model. Validation must use the INotifyDataErrorInfo interfce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two pointer besides the fact that this question is too broad (just get started and ask smaller questions):

1. Do not roll your own MVVM framework. Although it is fun to do so, it adds a lot of work and it's better to rely on proven code.
2. As for deciding when to add the data to the database: that depends on functional requirements. What does the user expect to happen and when?

**EDIT**

Master detail is very simple in Silverlight:

1. Create a collection.
2. Bind an Items control to the list and set its IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to true.
3. Then bind a ContentControl to the same collection.
4. Add a ContentTemplate in the ContentControl that contains controls to display the details/fields by using binding.

If you put the content control in a UserControl you can easily support adding items to the collection by:
 1. Adding an empty item (or with default values) to the collection
 2. Make the new Item the current item by selecting it in the ItemsCollection. This way the new element will be available for editing.

With some tweaking it is possible to support more complex scenarios but in a nutshell this is it.

Comment: I was simply wanting to know the best way to create a Master/Detail form populated initially with several rows in the child. Vortex basically confirmed the approach I had in my head is proabably the best solution. I don't really have a question about when to add to the database. 

MVVM: I am hesitant to learn too many new things at once. I was simply going to add a "ViewModel" directory with classes that implements IPropertyChanged. Seems pretty simple?? Am I over simplyfying it? I was basing this off a tutorial on the Silverlight.net site: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/CL09

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use something that implements ICollectionView to keep them synchronized?

Comment: @James Maning: When you set IsSynchronzedWithCurrentItem=True on an ItemsControl, the ItemsControl will in fact update the default ICollectionView with the SelectedItem. When you Bind a ContentControl to the same collection, it will bind to the same CollectionView and show the CurrentItem. All automatically.

Comment: @Emo: very nice!  I guess I'm confused as to how the second guy binding to the same collection gets access to the ICollectionView that was created by the first control when it was binding to the collection (again, in the scenario that what you're binding to isn't already implementing ICollectionView).  I would've guessed that the first control wouldn't have any ability to 'export' the created ICollectionView, leaving the second control stuck in terms of trying to sync via the same ICollectionView created by the first.